# Fetch data from MySQL using OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm a beginner in OOP PHP.
I'm trying to make a class that will connect,query and fetch data
I done the below coding

```
class MySQL {

    private $set_host;
    private $set_username;
    private $set_password;
    private $set_database;

     public function __Construct($set_host, $set_username, $set_password){
        $this->host = $set_host;
        $this->username = $set_username;
        $this->password = $set_password;
        $con= mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        if(!$con){ die("Couldn't connect"); }
    }


    public function Database($set_database)
    {   
        $this->database=$set_database;
        mysql_select_db($this->database)or die("cannot select Dataabase");
    }

    public function Fetch($set_table_name){
        $this->table_name=$set_table_name;
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name); 
    $result= mysql_fetch_array($query);
    }
}

$connect = new MySQL('localhost','root','');
$connect->Database('cms');
$connect->Fetch('posts');
```

what I'm trying to achieve is this

```
$connect = new MySQL('localhost','root','');
$connect->Database('cms');
$connect->Fetch('posts');
```

and I want to fetch the data using a format like this

```
echo $result[0];
```

but I'm not getting that logic to make this happen
please help

Thanks!

Comment: $this is used to access the object's variables, not local variables. You should also give a look at MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: You shouldn't `die()` in your class. Better to throw an exception upward

Comment: +1 for Manhim's comment about [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Start with these and then extend them instead of constructing something around the old `mysql` extension. In fact unless you have to support an old version of PHP, or need to work around legacy code you shouldnt even be using the `mysql` extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `Fetch` function is only pulling one row from the database, and you aren't returning the results...

The method isn't the best, but in order to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
public function Fetch($set_table_name){
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$set_table_name); 
    $result = array();
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         $result[] = $record;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This will make each row a part of $result, but you'll have to access it like this:

You would call the fetch function like this:

```
$result = $connect->Fetch('posts');

echo $result[0]['columnName'];  // for row 0;
```

Or in a loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($result); $x++) {
   echo $result[$x][0] . "<BR>";  // outputs the first column from every row
}
```

That said, fetching the entire result set into memory is not a great idea (some would say it's a very bad idea.)

Edit: It also looks like you have other issues with your class...  I have to run but will check back tomorrow and if others haven't set you straight I will expand.

Edit2: Ok, going to do a once-over on your class and try to explain a few things:

```
class MySQL {

  //declaring the private variables that you will access through $this->variable;
  private $host;  
  private $username;
  private $password;
  private $database;
  private $conn;  // Adding the connection, more on this later.

  public function __Construct($set_host, $set_username, $set_password){
    $this->host = $set_host;
    $this->username = $set_username;
    $this->password = $set_password;
    // Combining the connection & connection check using 'or'
    // Notice that I removed the semi-colon after the mysql_connect function
    $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
                  or die("Couldn't connect");
  }

  public function Database($set_database)
  {   
    $this->database=$set_database;
    // Adding the connection to the function allows you to have multiple 
    // different connections at the same time.  Without it, it would use
    // the most recent connection.
    mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->conn) or die("cannot select Dataabase");
  }

  public function Fetch($table_name){
    // Adding the connection to the function and return the result object instead
    return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name, $this->conn);         
  }

}

$connect = new MySQL('localhost','root','');
$connect->Database('cms');
$posts = $connect->Fetch('posts');

if ($posts && mysql_num_rows($posts) > 0) {
     echo "Here is some post data:<BR>";
     while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($posts)) {
         echo $record[0];  // or a quoted string column name instead of numerical index.
     }
} else {
     echo "No posts!";
}
```

I hope this helps... It should get you started at least.  If you have more questions you should ask them separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.this is what I'm looking for.
Thanks a lot :)
+100Likes :)

Comment: I have a lot similar kind of questions to ask and  how much do I need to give you to answer my ridiculous crazy question? 
I don't want to annoy you ,that's why
:)

Comment: @asker: ITs great that this is an snwer to your question and you should give Fosco an upvote and the answer points (click the check mark graphic) but **PLEASE** look into using Mysqli or PDO for what you are trying to do. See My and Manhim's comments to your question.

Comment: I'm new here and it says "Vote up requires 15 reputation"
:(

Comment: Ahh... i forgot there were minumums. I Think you should still be able to select his answer though.

Comment: @Fosco: If he is really trying to learn OOP you should teach him how to throw/try/catch instead of using the `die` statements in the class :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because $result is set inside the Fetch function.  It won't be available outside the Fetch function.

Instead of this line `$result= mysql_fetch_array($query);`, you'll want something like `return mysql_fetch_array($query);`.

And then in your code

```
$row = $connect->Fetch('posts');
// do something with $row
```

On another note, your Fetch function only applies to database queries that return one row.  You'll have to separate the mysql_query & mysql_fetch_array calls into another function if you want to loop through rows in a query result.

And on another note, you shouldn't need to encapsulate this code into a class.  PHP already provides OOP-based database classes called PDO, or PHP Data Objects.  There's a learning curve to it, but it's best practice, and will help secure your code against things like SQL injection.

This is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2478

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function that returns the value of the object.

```
public function returnData($data){
  return $this->$data;
}
```

Then within the page you wish to get the data on just initiate the class and call the function within that class.

```
$post->returnDate("row name here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
 //database.php  
 class Databases{  
      public $con;  
      public function __construct()  
      {  
           $this->con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "giit");  
           if(!$this->con)  
           {  
                echo 'Database Connection Error ' . mysqli_connect_error($this->con);  
           }  
      }  
      public function insert($table_name, $data)  
      {  
           $string = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (";            
           $string .= implode(",", array_keys($data)) . ') VALUES (';            
           $string .= "'" . implode("','", array_values($data)) . "')";  
           if(mysqli_query($this->con, $string))  
           {  
                return true;  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo mysqli_error($this->con);  
           }  
      }  
      public function selectmulti($selecttype,$table_name)  
      {  
           $array = array();  
           $query = "SELECT ".$selecttype." FROM ".$table_name."";  
           $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
           {  
                $array[] = $row;  
           }  
           return $array;  
      } 
     public function selectsingle($selecttype,$table_name)  
      {   
           $query = "SELECT ".$selecttype." FROM ".$table_name."";  
           $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);  
           $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

           return $row;  
      }  
 } 

 ?>  

<?php
$data = new Databases;  
$post_data = $data->selectmulti('*','centerdetail');  

$n = 1;
foreach($post_data as $post)  
{ 
    echo $n.'.'.$post['CenterCode'].'___';
    $n += 1;
}

echo '<br>';


$post_data = $data->selectsingle('*','centerdetail');  

echo $post_data['CenterCode'];

?>
```